# Need to get Jenkins Password Parameter value in plain text

Tags: jenkins

I have a parameterized jenkins job and I am using a password parameter, which I need to pass to another parameter.By adding that in ref, and fetching by name like a normal param it gives value as . I want to fetch its value in plain text. "Paramname.getPlainText()" does not work.

Fetching password parameter value as plain text in another parMeter to pass it to call api.

Able to access the password in build steps by $pass.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the plaintext value from a password parameter in a pipeline is surprisingly straightforward. You can just call `toString()` on it:

```
params.MY_PASSWORD_PARAMETER.toString()
```